# How do I use Tweepy OAuth for Twitter's new API?

Tags: python, authentication, twitter, oauth, tweepy

I have been working with the Twitter API for a few months now, and everything has been working great, but suddenly my code fails to authenticate.

I have researched the problem, and it turns out Twitter has deprecated the old authentication process.  I cannot figure out how to authenticate with the new API version.

I am using Tweepy version 2.0 with Python 2.7

Here is my code:

```
auth = tweepy.auth.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

if api.test() is True:
    return api
else:
    print 'Invalid Authentication'
    return None
```

If somebody could share their working code, that would be great!  Thanks.

Edit:  I would like to add that I have looked at Tweepy's documentation.  The provided authentication tutorial does not work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, upgrade `tweepy` to the latest version directly from the github (2.1 version now):

```
git clone https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy.git
python setup.py install
```

Then, don't rely on `api.test()` now - it [makes a call](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/tweepy/api.py#L489) to `help/test.json` which is [not supported](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/help/test) in 1.1 version (take a look at `api.verify_credentials` method instead - will return `False` in case of problems).

Hope that helps.

Comment: That worked.  Thanks for the help!  I really don't like the new rate limits, but I guess I will have to adapt!